# What does Gt and Go RAM mean on my Surface Pro 9 packaging?

Tags: memory, microsoft-surface-pro

There is a sticker on the packaging for my Surface Pro 9 which I assume is some kind of technical specification, but I don't fully understand it.

[image: Photo of label on packaging]

If I look in Task Manager I can see I do indeed have 8GB of RAM. So what is Go and Gt? And how does this relate to the 256GB of storage? And what is Graphite in this context?

Comment: I wonder if its just the same thing in 'different' languages?

Comment: I'd agree with @JourneymanGeek here. In French it would be 256Go (Giga - octets)

Comment: What's Gt tho? I'd figure german or spanish, but I've no idea what to check to confirm that :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'd guess it should be available somewhere in the locale files of Linux which I would expect to be used for commands to do easy regionalisation and *should* be freely available, but I don't have any system on which I can easily download or rummage through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go is GB in french - feels weird to cite reddit, but [here we are](https://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/am7nnl/why_are_digital_storage_units_gigabyte_terabyte/).

I *think* Gt is [finnish](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tavu_(tietotekniikka)) - but its bit of an educated guess from googling 8Gt and working backwords.

Graphite is the colour, since there's colour variations for the same model